# Mongodb, create index on a subdocument which is a list

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Is it possible to create index on `name` field in `fruit` subdocument ?

```
{                                                                               
    "trees": 5,
    "fruit":[{"name":"apple", "color":"red"}, {"name":"pear", "color":"green"}]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.yourCollection.ensureIndex({"fruit.name":1})
```

Comment: Is there a link to documentation? I have not found.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents